# Flatten last layer of nested list using comprehension

Tags: python

How can I flatten the last layer of a nested list?

```
lista = [['a'],['b']]
listb = [['c']]
nested = [lista, listb]

# [[['a'], ['b']], [['c']]]
# how to get [['a', 'b'], ['c']]?

[[x for x in y] for y in nested]
# gives [[['a'], ['b']], [['c']]]
```

I tried with unpacking but it is disallowed in list comprehension.

For more context, the reason the last elements are always 1-element list is that I get this result by using:

```
[myfunc(x) for x in y for y in other_nested_list]
```

Comment: itertools `chain.fromiterator`

Comment: thanks, care to expand?

Comment: @bn_ln That's called [`chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable).

Answer (score 3):

```
lista = [['a'],['b']]
listb = [['c']]
nested = [lista, listb]

# [[['a'], ['b']], [['c']]]
# how to get [['a', 'b'], ['c']]?

print([[x for x in y] for y in nested])
# gives [[['a'], ['b']], [['c']]]


#simple solution:
print([[x[0] for x in y] for y in nested])
# gives [['a', 'b'], ['c']]


#solution with itertools (it will work to list with multiple items inside it too):
import itertools
print([list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([x for x in y])) for y in nested])
# gives [['a', 'b'], ['c']]


#solution with `unlist()` (== with itertools still):
def unlist(lst):
    return list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(lst))

print([unlist([x for x in y]) for y in nested])
# gives [['a', 'b'], ['c']]
```

Comment: that could work, just wondering if there's something more general that could work on more than 1-item lists as well.

Comment: @Alexander 's vertion `listc = [j for i in nested for j in i]` will work for any amount of items inside

Comment: this is the most promising answer yet, I'm just not a fan of using `x[0]`, I'd prefer something more general like R's `unlist(x)`...

Comment: I guess `itertools.chain` is that more general thing you're looking for

Answer (score 1):

List comprehension isn't needed, so if it's not a fixed requirement for some other reason, you can just add the lists together with `+`:

```py
lista = ['a','b']
listb = ['c']
nested = [lista] + [listb]

print(nested)
```

Output:

```text
[['a', 'b'], ['c']]
```

Comment: thanks but this nested list is the result of a function and I therefore don't have the children lists in memory or assigned to variables, question edited

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension:

```
lista = ['a','b']
listb = ['c']
nested = [[lista], [listb]]
listc = [j for i in nested for j in i]
print(listc)
```

or you can use itertools

```
import itertools
lista = ['a','b']
listb = ['c']
nested = [[lista], [listb]]
listc = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(nested))
print(listc)
```

output:

```
[['a', 'b'], ['c']]
[['a', 'b'], ['c']]
```

---

update

you can use both examples from above and then

```
lista = [[['a'], ['b']], [['c']]]
listb = [j for i in lista for j in i]
listc = [listb[0] + listb[1], listb[2]]
print(listc)
```

output

```
[['a', 'b'], ['c']]
```

Comment: thihs does not yield the expected result for my particular case, see edited question

Comment: @gaut  now I am confused you want to go from `[[a],[b],[c]]` to `[[a,b],[c]]`?

Comment: from `[[['a'], ['b']], [['c']]]` to `[['a', 'b'], ['c']]`, basically removing the last layer of 1-item lists.

Comment: @gaut  that is what both of my examples would do it just wouldn't merge the list that contains two elements.  I can create a solution that would do that but it would only work on that exact output format

Comment: both examples give `[['a'], ['b'], ['c']]`, removing the second layer I believe

Comment: @gaut  right so if you were to merge the first 2 it would be the output you wanted correct?  see the update to my answer

Comment: I was hoping for something where I don't have to specify the list formatting manually. basically I get this list by using `[myfunc(x) for x in y for y in other_nested_list]`, guess I'll try to modify this. thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own function that will run recursively where you will tell at which level do you want to unpack your list

```
nested = [[['a'], ['b']], [['c']]]
def unstack(l, level):
    if level == 1:
        return l[0]
    res = []
    for i in l:
        if isinstance(i, list):
            res.append(unstack(i, level-1))
        else:
            res.append(i)
    return res

unstack(nested, 3)  # [['a', 'b'], ['c']]
```

It will work for each nested layer, you have to provide the level till which you want to unstack this list.

Comment: this gives `TypeError: add expected 2 arguments, got 3` (my question was just edited, see above)

Comment: What input you are trying to give and what is your expected output now? Because it is working with the former case. output `[['a', 'b'], ['c']]`

Comment: I realised with some answers that my question needed a better specification. the edited question is closer to my actual problem.

Comment: I tried to input the list you have given in the question, I am getting the output you told in the question

Comment: `list(reduce(lambda x, y: [*x, *y] , nested))` like Alexander's answer, yields `[['a'], ['b'], ['c']]` instead of `[['a', 'b'], ['c']]`. I still get the same error on the first example

Comment: @gaut now can you check it  will work

Comment: @MechanicPig can you check now .